# Unable to push Docker image to Gitlab group Container Registry

Tags: docker, gitlab, containers, gitlab-ci

I have created a light-weight Node.js Docker image (`my-node-image`) that I want to be able to push and use on different projects, all hosted on Gitlab. In order to achieve that, I wanted to publish the image to the Container Registry of my group (`my-group`), which contains all my projects, but I have been met with failure.

I have done the following :

1. Creating a Deploy token on my group (`MY_DEPLOY_TOKEN`) with all the permissions granted.
2. Logging in to my group using `docker login -u MY_DEPLOY_TOKEN_USERNAME -p MY_DEPLOY_TOKEN_PASSWORD registry.gitlab.com`, which returned `Login Succeeded`.
3. Building my image following the Gitlab naming conventions : `docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/my-group/my-node-image .`, which succeeded.
4. Pushing the image to my-group's Container Registrty using : `docker push registry.gitlab.com/my-group/my-node-image`, which returned the error `denied: requested access to the resource is denied`.

I don't know if this is related, but when I run the docker login command after successfully logging in, I'm still prompted to identify myself, and I don't receive the usual `Authenticating with existing credentials...`

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Are you able to push your image to the project's container registry rather than the group one? Might help to understand if the problem relates to it being a group registry or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to pull your Docker images from within your GitLab pipelines, then using the provided CI token should be enough:

`docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY`

It is the best approach so you don't have to worry about manually maintaining these credentials, as the pipelines will have always access to the registry. All of these variables are explained in [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) part of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

While for the [Package](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/package_registry/#view-packages) and [Container](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#view-the-container-registry) Registry, viewing and pulling packages on the group level is allowed, it does not seem to be allowed to push anything on the group-level in general.

I suppose the group level view is just a way to collect information from multiple registries, there is no actual group-registry. This would also explain, why it is not possible to push anything on this level.

However the docs do mention the possibility to use a Project as a collective package registry: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/workflows/project_registry.html

I think it is worth trying, if this also works for container images.